# Is it possible for my continent to be in one of the black bordered areas of Pangea?

Tags: internal-consistency, environment

[image: Pangea]

Is it possible for my continent millions of years ago to have been in one of the black-bordered areas of Pangea without changing anything in modern-day after all continents have split. By without changing anything, I mean the climate and the ecosystem.

Comment: It possible? Of course. Is it extreeeeemly unlikely? Also yes. Basically, you are introducing a *massive* change 200 to 300 million years ago, and hope that by an astronomically improbable stroke of unbelievable luck the ripples caused by the change will somehow cancel each other completely. (And, of course, the continent must have sunk a long time ago; you cannot have an extra continent above water and not change the climate.)

Comment: What I mean is it was always there and split with all the other continents

Comment: Does it matter if it would or not? It's your world, you set the rules. What worldbuilding problem (what rule development or rule application) are you having trouble with?

Comment: Could there have been other continental cratons in Pangea? Sure. Would our modern Earth look the same? No chance.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, no. The problem is you're asking for a continent, which usually means a large landmass based on some kind of cratons, and cratons usually don't just disappear. They can get jostled around or merge into one another, but they're very large masses of slightly less dense rock that "float" on top of the denser oceanic rocks. [Even Zealandia, which is mostly sunken, has a cratonic core which broke off when Zealandia itself broke off from Australia](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/geology/article-abstract/41/2/231/131212/Extreme-persistence-of-cratonic-lithosphere-in-the?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

The broader problem is your continent is way too big to just disappear. Looking at the three outlined areas in your figure, the *smallest* one of these appears to be about three times the size of Australia, and the largest is about the same size as India, Madagascar, Australia, and Antarctica put together (though I suspect Antarctica is undersized on that map). That is magnitudes larger than Zealandia, a continent of that size which would be easier to get away with. A craton of that size wouldn't just vanish. It would still be floating around in the present day, and the very existence of an eighth continent, even if you had some magical barrier preventing it from being settled by plants and animals, would disrupt global wind and rainfall patterns or global currents. An eighth continent could have easily accelerated the onset of the Ice Age, or disrupted the Circum-Antarctic current such that the Ice Age never happened. Or it could have bridged an otherwise unbridgeable ocean gap and done things like...say, allowed placental mammals to island hop to Australia.

This isn't even accounting for it doing things like disrupting the climate of Pangaea, which already had issues with internal desertification due to its sheer size. For example your middle proposed zone would have desertified much of southern Europe. IRL this area has a number of well-known coastal and marine Lagerstatten such as Monte San Giorgio and the Zorzino Limestone, which is where reptiles like *Tanystropheus* and *Drepanosaurus* come from, and is home to some of the earliest known pterosaurs. The history of paleontology in this world, if nothing else, would be dramatically different because most of the fossiliferous marine Triassic to early Jurassic rocks that paleontology was built on (i.e., where the first discovered ichthyosaurs and plesiosaurs came from) wouldn't exist.

Even if it sank, the existence of a large submerged continental shelf would dramatically affect ocean currents and marine evolution, such as allowing species to migrate across the Pacific by using the sunken continent as a temporary stop. Temporary island chains similar to these between Africa and South America are one way in which rodents and monkeys are thought to have rafted to South America.